# Empty patch created using "git format-patch origin/master --stdout"

Tags: git, apache-drill

I was looking into Drill's(*open source github project*) documentation to [create a patch](https://drill.apache.org/docs/apache-drill-contribution-guidelines/#creating-a-patch).

I came across this command:

```
git format-patch origin/master --stdout > DRILL-1234.1.patch.txt
```

I made some changes. I verified my changes by `git status`. I modified a **.java** file. I tried above-mentioned command to create a patch.

I opened `DRILL-1234.1.patch.txt` & its **empty**.

Then I tried `git add <modified file>` & tried the same command, still **empty** patch file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note: [Git 2.41 Q2 2023 `git format-patch` does manage empty commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34692447/6309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git `format-patch` creates patches from commits. So you have to perform `git commit` first.

Also - I don't think `--stdout` does what you think it does.

From here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch

> The names of the output files are printed to standard output, unless
>   the --stdout option is specified.

`format-patch` creates one patch file for each commit you have. It does not output the file itself, but the name of the patches files.

Answer (score 3):

You must have some content (commits) in order to create path.
Commit your changes and the create a patch

```
git format-patch HEAD~X // x is the number of commits you need
```